# Change Magento from multiple stores with multiple domains to multiple stores on one domain

Tags: magento

I currently have 3 magento stores, each has its own domain name. (just the ltd is different)

I want to change this so that I just have one tld, the .com. But I want to keep the seperate stores.

How can I change this back? Do I simply just remove the code from the index.php file, and change it in config?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not show any effort what has been tried and/or read.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done from Admin

1. Go to Magento Admin
2. Navigate to System -> Manage Store. There you will see all your websites, stores and store view.
3. You'll your stores in second column. Click on them and change Website (top row)
4. Save

Good luck!